# Deseleccionar un button (no es checkbox)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap

Agradecería mucho si alguien pudiese ayudarme con esto ya que todavía soy primeriza en esto: 
Dentro de una sección de la página, donde hay 5 botones (provienen desde un json), me deje seleccionar varios de esos botones, ya sea uno o todos, tienen un estilo para activo y otro para inactivo, entonces al darle clic otra vez, se deseleccionen (no es deshabilitar) sino que se queden con su estilo inactivo.

```
moduloToc.controller('ctrlDatos', function($scope) {
$scope.estadoActivo = "btn btn-default";
$scope.estadoInactivo = "btn btn-info";

  $scope.cambiarEstado = function(event) {
    var idElemSel = "#" + event.target.id;
    $(document).ready(function() {
      if ($(idElemSel).click) {
        $(idElemSel).addClass('activo');
      } else {
        $(idElemSel).removeClass('inactivo');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Que error te devuelve ?

Comment: que id's le pones a los botones, varian?

Comment: si, depende de cual estés seleccionando, uno se llama cd, limDto, central, oDeS, y conexion

Comment: supongo que son buttons o son input's ?

Comment: si, son buttons

Comment: ok ya modifique la respuesta a ver si te sirve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se si entendí bien pero lo que creo que quieres hacer es poner un botón deshabilitado lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('moduloToc',['$scope', function($scope){

    $('button').on('click', function() {

       var urlid = $(this).attr('id');

       if($("#"+urlid).hasClass("active")) 
           $("#"+urlid).removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
       else    
           $("#"+urlid).removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');

    });
}]);
```

El html no se como lo tengas pero yo lo hice de esta manera:

```
<div ng-controller="moduloToc">
    <button id="uno" class="active">button 1</button>
    <button id="dos" class="active">button 2</button>
    <button id="tres" class="inactive">button 3</button>
</div>
```

aquí esta el [ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/josegoyo/6b6cpkfk/10/)

Comment: Agradezco mucho tu comentario, pero no quiero desabilitarlo, (disculpa que mi pregunta no se haya entendido bien).

Comment: bueno ya cambie la respuesta a ver si asi te sirve, ahi abajo puse el link al ejemplo